# Attaching an event to an Iframe that contains more iframes

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, iframe

I have an editor which is in my `window` that contains a wrapping iframe and then 2 more iframes inside like (the HTML inside the `<iframe>` element is inserted via `write()` in JS, not hardcoded like this):

```
<iframe class="parent">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <iframe class="editor"></iframe>
    <iframe class="previewer"></iframe>
  </div>
</iframe>
```

One is an editor, the other is a previewer. The first one that contains the two (we'll call this the `parent`) has an eventListener for `mousemove` attached to it, but nothing is firing. If i add a `5px` border for example, the event will fire when I move my mouse on the border of the `parent`, but not when i hover over the middle which contains the editor *or* previewer (previewer is `display:none` while the editor is visible, and vice versa).

So, the blue area in the following i can `mousemove`, but the rest I can't. It's most likely because of the stacking order, but how can I attach an event to fire on the entire frame? I need `mousemove` because on `mousemove` I display a menu in the bottom right. I want the same menu to display whether or not the editor or the previewer is visible.

[image: editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anyway to do this because the event is caught in the children iframes. My "fix" was to manually set the same event to all the iframes like:

```
// Hide and show the util bar based on mouse movements
eventableIframes = [self.previewerIframeDocument, self.editorIframeDocument];

for (i = 0; i < eventableIframes.length; i++) {
  eventableIframes[i].addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    utilBarHandler(e);
  });
  eventableIframes[i].addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    utilBarHandler(e);
  });
  eventableIframes[i].addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    shortcutUpHandler(e);
  });
  eventableIframes[i].addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    shortcutHandler(e);
  });
}
```

Very ugly, but no other way.